# What should be on topic here?

Tags: discussion

[The help center about what topics you can ask about here](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is really vague, saying just

> If your question is not specifically on-topic for Cardano Stack Exchange, it may be on topic for another Stack Exchange site.

While it is fairly easy to tell what the site is about based on the name, people new to this site might be thrown off by this, as it doesn’t give that much information. What should this page eventually look like, and what should be on-topic in the future?

Edit: specifying in the aforementioned page with something about cryptocurrency, while not going to specific (for reasons described by Stephane Rollands comment) would be nice in the meantime

Comment: This discussion (linked thereafter) has modified my perception about fixing the frames/borders of the site before we actually see the population using it, and before we have achieved a sufficient threshold of user/questionners. I'm just pointing to it here as it may be of interest regarding your question: https://cardano.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3/are-trading-traders-questions-appropriate-for-the-site